# Merge compressed lzo files in HDFS less than 128MB

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to merge small hdfs files of Kb size into 128MB size files . 
All those kb size files are lzo compressed 
Can anyone help with this?Here is what i tried so far .

```
hadoop jar
   /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.15.1.jar
   -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=10 -Dmapred.reduce.output.compression.codec=lzo  -Dmapred.output.compress=true mapred.output.compression.type=lzo -input "/user/input"
   -output "/user/input_tmp"
   -mapper cat -reducer cat
```

The issue here is my output is uncompressed part files but i want it as compressed .lzo files like part-r-00001.lzo...

Comment: You may use HAR (Hadoop Archives)

Answer (score 0):

See the examples here https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/HadoopStreaming.html

space between -D and the property name is required.
Also 
you can use

`-D mapred.output.compression.codec=com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec`instead

```
-Dmapred.reduce.output.compression.codec=lzo
```

Also check your xsite.xmls like core-site and mapred-site.xmls are cofigured with LZO properly